# Is there a term for the "no base building" levels in real-time strategy games?

Tags: terminology

In a lot of real-time strategy games I've played (Age of Empires II, Warcraft III, and StarCraft II come to mind), some of the levels of the single-player campaign usually involve you controlling a handful of units and achieving your objective without managing a base. Typically these levels are laid-out linearly, with a set path or series of paths for you to follow until a pre-defined endpoint. The game will also usually give you more units along the way as a means to replenish your army. There is no base building or economy management involved the level, though occasionally you might get access to a few unit-production buildings to also replenish your army.

These levels seem like such a common occurrence in RTS's that I'm wondering if there's a term for them? "No base building" seems like a bit of a clunky name for it.

Comment: I've heard them referred to as "dungeon levels" in Warcraft 3 and "predeployed maps" in Advance Wars, but I don't think either term is widely acknowledged.

Comment: I've heard a guide for Warcraft 3 call it a "dungeon crawl", which works perfectly well for those levels, but not so well for games like Age of Empires, where its more like a "map crawl".

Comment: In Starcraft, these were called "installation missions". I'm not sure that term has really been used much since.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the only allowed terminology questions ask to define a gaming-related term, not to find a noun that describes some gaming-related feature.

Comment: @Wrigglenite https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11472/127901

Comment: @Dragonrage I'm not sure why you're linking that. "I do believe that there is ample precedent that questions asking to define one thing about one game are much much better than questions asking to give a thing a name in one game, which in turns are much much better than questions about multiple games, entire game genres or even all of the games ever." This question is the worst case possible, as detailed in that answer.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Is there an actual consensus for that somewhere?  The meta topic about it that Dragonrage linked to shows two answers only one vote apart.

Comment: @Powerlord Yes, the terminology tag wiki.

Comment: @Wrigglenite Quite literally anyone with enough rep can modify tag wikis.

Comment: @Powerlord Look at the edit history, it's always been that way. These questions are too broad and primarily opinion based.

Comment: It's disingenuous to say it's always been that way when the relevant excerpt edit was made less than a year ago without community consensus (not even suggestion), and the full tag history has never mentioned this.

Comment: @Schism From the first revision: "It is not appropriate for repository style questions that seek to span the terminology graph. While collecting terminology is within the mandate of Gaming.SE, single questions which ask for a list of answers (with one term per answer) do not fit well into the engine and are likely to be closed.". This is from 2010, and was unchanged until January 2019, where it was made even clearer that questions should ask about what a term means, *not* if there's a term for a specific feature. See the three example questions that were edited in.

Comment: @Schism If you want to continue this discussion, I'd suggest you post a question on meta, as comments are not the place for this.

Answer (score 6):

I would think the term [RTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_tactics) (real time tactics) would be a good fit. It is a sub/related genre to RTS, and is "focused on tactical and operational aspects of warfare such as unit formations or the exploitation of terrain for tactical advantage" as opposed to the "logistics and production".

I have also heard the terms non-base building used fairly frequently. Alternatively, I've heard the term "Call ins" used to refer to games where you simply call in the troops you need to fight with as opposed to building them.

Answer (score -1):

Years ago, these were called **installation missions**. Some Google searching suggests that this term probably isn't in common usage at this point. You can find it in some walkthroughs or reviews of the original Starcraft.

I believe this term is in reference to the [Jacobs Installation](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jacobs_Installation_%28mission%29) mission, which was the fourth mission in Starcraft, and the first one without any base building.

Comment: Command and Conquer (1995) had these kinds of missions before StarCraft (2000) did, so I'm pretty sure StarCraft wasn't the origin of the name for these kinds of level missions.

Comment: @MarkRipley Were they called "Installation" missions in C&C?